# Need Some Clarification on Signing Off a Letter

Tags: email, letter-writing

Can you sign off a letter with the following:

> Dear Joe,
>
> I appreciated the cake you sent me.
>
> Thank you,
>
> Bob

But doesn't the above sound like you're thanking yourself (Bob) instead of Joe? "Thank you, Bob"

Another one:

> Dear Joe,
>
> See you after the new year.
>
> Merry Christmas,
>
> Bob

Again, doesn't the above sound like you're saying merry Christmas to yourself (Bob) instead of Joe? "Merry Christmas, Bob"

Comment: Not at all. They both sound like you are addressing Joe.

Comment: If you follow the OP's suggestion, every sign-off to a letter would be interpreted incorrectly. Yours sincerely, Bob. I remain your obedient servant, Bob. All addressed to Bob.

Answer (score 1):

No. You are writing

> Merry Christmas,
>
> Bob

not

> Merry Christmas, Bob.

The first form follows the conventional form of an epistolatory valediction, and would be read in the same way as

> Yours faithfully,
>
> Bob

But even if you *had* written the second form, all on one line, convention takes over.

Comment: Why is a comma used instead of any other punctuation like a period?

Comment: @NoName 1: It's not a sentence. 2: It's convention.